# How to declare circular queue in pika

Tags: rabbitmq, pika, python-pika

Is it possible to declare a queue in `pika` (`python-pika`) as a **circular queue** ? If yes, how ?

I mean by circular queue (or a ring) is a queue when a message is selected it will be re-inserted at the end of the queue, instead of removing it from the queue. For example, if the queue contains: `msg_3`, `msg_2`, `msg_1`, then after a consumer get `msg_1`, the latter will be inserted at the end, so the queue will be: `msg_1`, `msg_3`, `msg_2` (instead of `msg_3`, `msg_2`)

**Edit**: As proposed by [IMSoP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157957/imsop), I can make the consumer republish every consumed message (for example, at the end of the callback function).

Comment: `circular queue` ?

Comment: I mean by circular queue (or a ring) is a queue when a message is selected it will be re-inserted at the end of the queue, instead of removing it from the queue. For example, if the queue contains: msg_3, msg_2, msg_1, then after a consumer get msg_1, the latter will be inserted at the end, so the queue will be: msg_1, msg_3, msg_2 (instead of msg_3, msg_2)

Comment: I think the simplest would be for your consumer to requeue the message after it reads it. Presumably, you want some way of it permanently removing a message anyway, so need to be able to control when it's requeued?

Comment: Thank you so much @IMSoP . that did the trick!